# How do I blur something in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make my top nav transparent (`opacity: 0.9`) and I want to make the background behind the top nav sort of blur (like Apple Inc has done here:)

[image]

How do I blur the background?

Comment: Blur effects are applied with a css filter: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Comment: Is that Apple example blurred? Or are they using a gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter):

```css
.background {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/640/240) center/cover;
  width: 600px;
  height: 240px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 40px 80px;
  color: white;
  
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Also check the [supportage](https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop-filter)

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. I will tick the answer when the site allows me to :) (8 minutes). Thank you very much

Comment: Which would work only in Blink (Webkit also has support behind prefix)